# How to Import Large mediawiki xml Dumps into existing wiki?

Tags: xml, mediawiki, dump

I have Several xml dumps. 
For example:
text-dump-1.xml - 200mb
text-dump-2.xml -222mb

Each of them are 200+ MBs and i wanna import all of them on my existing mediawiki database without deleting any of its contents. I'm new to mediawiki and i wanna know how can i do that?

Answer (score 3):

You need to run importDump.php from your maintenance folder.

`php importDump.php < dumpfile.xml`

Do it multiple times, once for each .xml file. It may take a while.

If the articles you are importing have links to images, you will need also to upload them to your server and run [importImages.php](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:ImportImages.php) as well, otherwise they will all become red links.

Comment: This will take days to weeks for something the size of wikipedia.